# Convert Dynamic Object to StringMap

Tags: haxe, openfl

I'm saving a StringMap to SharedObject using OpenFl

**Save to SharedObject**

```
SO.data.users_arr = new StringMap<Dynamic>();
SO.data.users_arr.set("user1",{varOne:1,varTwo:2});
```

**Retrieve from SharedObject**

```
var users_arr : StringMap<Dynamic> = cast(SO.data.users_arr, StringMap<Dynamic>);
```

The retrieve gives me an error:

```
[Fault] exception, information=TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert Object@b868371 to haxe.ds.StringMap.
lib/sim/model/SOControl.hx:37: characters 20-21 : Unexpected .
```

The question is: How can I reconvert a previously saved StringMap from a Dynamic Object?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try an unsafe cast `var users_arr : StringMap<Dynamic> = cast SO.data.users_arr;`?

Comment: Otherwise I would recommend to just use `Dynamic` instead of a StringMap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution is probably to use the [Serialization mechanism built into Haxe](https://haxe.org/manual/std-serialization.html). Here's some pseudo-code of how that could look like:

**Saving:**

```
SO.data.users_arr = Serializer.run(users_arr);
```

**Loading:**

```
var users_arr:StringMap<Dynamic> = Unserializer.run(SO.data.users_arr);
```

Comment: Yep, I think that should do it. I thought that there was a way without serializing. Thanks.